# Как полностью удалить сообщение из почты? (C#, MailKit, MimeKit)

Tags: c#, email, mailkit

Как полностью удалить сообщение из почты (не путать с перемещением в корзину)?
пробовал использовать метод

```
   MailFolder.SetFlagsAsync(UniqueId uid, 
                            MessageFlags flags,
                            bool silent,
                            CancellationToken cancellationToken = null)
```

и этот

```
   MailFolder.AddFlagsAsync Method (UniqueId uid,
                                 MessageFlags flags,
                                 bool silent,
                                 CancellationToken cancellationToken = null)
```

но они сообщение с сервера так и не удаляют. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?
Вот мой код

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("Вы точно хотите полностью УДАЛИТЬ сообщение?", "Удаление сообщение", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    var cells = dgvMessages.SelectedCells.GetEnumerator();
                    cells.MoveNext();
                    var uid = (UniqueId)((DataGridViewTextBoxCell)cells.Current).Value;
                    await _openFolder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite, _token);
                    IMailFolder trash = null;
                    _folders.ToList().ForEach(folder =>
                    {
                        if (folder.Attributes.HasFlag(FolderAttributes.Trash))
                        {
                            trash = folder;
                        }
                    });
                    await _openFolder.AddFlagsAsync(uid, MessageFlags.Deleted, false, _token);
                    dgvMessages.Rows.Remove(dgvMessages.CurrentRow);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался

```
await _openFolder.AddFlagsAsync(uid, MessageFlags.Deleted, false, _token);
if (_clientProfile.Client.Capabilities.HasFlag(ImapCapabilities.UidPlus))
{
     await _openFolder.ExpungeAsync(new UniqueId[] { uid });
     dgvMessages.Rows.Remove(dgvMessages.CurrentRow);
}
```